# How do I set up the vertex and edge of the story using azure cosmosDB gremlin?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, graph-databases

Trying to save Aesop's Fables Fox and Grapes using azure CosmosDB Gremlin. It tries to store detailed information such as why the fox gave up, where the grapes are, and when. How do I express it with vertices and edges?

Comment: I think you can share more details on this database, such as why you'd like to use gremlin to save the story. From your description on your case, What I can think of is that 3 vertices(fox, grape, tree), fox with property favorite fruit grape, with the ability jump, with the habit of making excuses. Grapes has properties ripe, yummy, and the tree has property tall. Fox wanna eat Grapes(edge), fox can't reach the branch of the tree, and grape hanging on branch of tree.

Answer (score 0):

based on my understandings, i will draw it like this picture that im uploading: [click here to see it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGpOF.png)

what i will do is :

1- to get the tree the fox need to climb the tree and get to the branch.
2- the moral of the story is he despite the grape when failed to do it, so he tried to achieved multiple times but it was hard for him so he despite it, which means he kept trying till he felt disappointment.

Now the scenario:

Fox is Hungry, he saw this tree with these branches some of grapes are ripe.
he tried to climb but he dont have the power to achieve the jump, so you increase the times of retry, increase the disappointment percentage and increase the ripe, he tried again and again ... so the retry time increase which will make the disappointment increased and some of the grapes will turn sour but some of them are ripe and good.

but i give this fox a solution, he have another tree where he can train his jumping and increase his climb power to climb to that tall tree. and i think i forgot to put the propriety of disappointment in the fox sorry :p

you can make it easier or you can make it excitement, i hope it was to your expectations.